# How to reinstall tensorflow .whl file built from source

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been [compiling TensorFlow from source for Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake) without any problems until now. In recent days, I cloned the r1.6.0 release, and set about building it for the GPU I have acquired. It built fine, the tutorial sample ran fine, but there was a version incompatibility because I somehow built Tensorflow using CUDA Toolkit 9.1 and tried to deploy it on a target PC with CUDA 9.0.

Regardless of whether I upgrade my build PC or downgrade the target PC, the `.whl` file produced by the build process will yield the same filename, and conceal all the version details. If I downgrade my build PC (my preference), when I try to `pip3 install tensorflow_gpu...etc.whl`, it essentially says that I'm using updated versions, and so does not change the installation. Trying `--force-reinstall` has no apparent effect either.

How can I get rid of everything installed by a "bad" `.whl` installation, and replace it with a "good" one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it's the "best" way, but so long as you have the original `.whl` file, you can `pip3 uninstall tensorflow-<original>.whl` and then `pip3 install tensorflow-<changed>.whl`. The two filenames will be the same, but the process will work.

In my case, rather than spend several hours rebuilding the original Tensorflow `.whl` installer from source, I recovered it from Windows Explorer's in-built "Previous Versions" ([shadow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy)) facility.